# Truncate every string in an array with JOLT Transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I try to truncate strings in an array with JOLT. The character "^" should be removed from any string that contains it in the first position.

**Sample Input:**

```json
{
  "scores": [
    "^aaaa",
    "^bbbb",
    "cccc",
    "^dddd",
    "eeee"
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
{
  "scores" : [ "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "eeee" ]
}
```

**My Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "splittedScores": "=split('\\^',@(1,scores))",
      "scores": "=join('',@(1,splittedScores))" // <--- Not working
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you'd need one extra **shift** transformation sandwiched between **modify** transformations to tame the subarrays such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('\\^',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "scores"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

or only one **shift** transformation will be sufficient to use(*a straightforward option*) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "^*": {
            "$(0,1)": "&3"
          },
          "*": {
            "$": "&3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

splitting by **`"$(0,1)"`** wildcard for the object under **`"^*"`** node. **&3** represents going three levels up to grab the name of the key **scores** .

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

If **^** is being removed *in the first position* really matters, then ***the second method***; if all **^** characters from any strings should be removed, then ***the first method*** should be used.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the extra shift!